# How do you make a function that will create a .jar file in Java?

Tags: java, file, jar

I've made some code in Java that will change some files in another .jar file, and I know that the unpacking/changing works, but the repacking doesn't. It does succeed, but when I compare the new one and the original (I removed the code that changed the files), they differed. What's interesting is that when I extracted them both into different directories, and I runned `diff -rqy` on them both, it didn't show any difference.

Here is the current function:

```
public static void add(File source, JarOutputStream target, String removeme)
        throws IOException
{
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    try
    {
        File source2 = new File(source.getPath().replaceAll("^" + removeme,
                ""));
        // File source2 = source;
        if (source.isDirectory())
        {
            String name = source2.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
            if (!name.isEmpty())
            {
                if (!name.endsWith("/"))
                    name += "/";
                JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
                entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
                target.putNextEntry(entry);
                target.closeEntry();
            }
            for (File nestedFile : source.listFiles())
                add(nestedFile, target, removeme);
            return;
        }

        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(source2.getPath().replace("\\", "/"));
        entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
        target.putNextEntry(entry);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        while (true)
        {
            int count = in.read(buffer);
            if (count == -1)
                break;
            target.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        target.closeEntry();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
JarOutputStream zip = new JarOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(JARFILE));
                for (File nestedFile : new File(DIRECTORY).listFiles())
                {
                    Utils.add(nestedFile, zip,
                            new File(DIRECTORY).getAbsolutePath());
                }
                zip.close();
```

Can anyone direct me on what to change in the function, or what other function I should use? The directory has subdirectories, so I need a function that will scan them.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I don't want something using the `jar` command, because I don't want the user to need to install the JDK. I want something using pure Java (libraries are OK, as long as I can include them in the program).

Edit 2: I'm making a Minecraft modder (like MCPatcher and ModLoader), but when I run `java -jar minecraft.jar`, it gives me this: `Invalid or corrupt jarfile`. The correct .jar doesn't give this (just a main class error, which is supposed to happen).

Comment: *How* are they different? And are they different in a meaningful way?

Comment: I have no idea. All that I can know of interest is a bunch of machine code from running `diff -a` on both lol.

Comment: Then how do you know what you're doing isn't working?

Comment: I've tested both of them, and only one started up (the other gave an error that it couldn't find a class, which I guess is the main class).

Comment: Why should they be equal? Even if all the member files are equal, any difference in the ZIP header (does it include times? are all the file attributes equal, including date/time?) will make the jars differ.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about that. The problem relies in that it cannot find the main class. They seem the same though.

Comment: Then when you unjarred them both your diff gave you misleading results. Without knowing the error you actually got, or actually running the code, it's difficult to help with the information provided. Have you tried debugging to see if walking the tree is actually working?

Comment: Wait, I've got some extra info. The good ones give an error that they cannot find the main class (they are supposed to give that), but this one gives "Invalid or corrupt jarfile".

Comment: I'm making a minecraft modding application (like ModLoader or MCPatcher) if that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you maybe interested in java.util.jar. This link maybe useful for you..

http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=32600

Comment: Yes, I know about that, and I've tried using that. Could you give a function that could work? I am clueless.

Comment: No, to be honest, I knew about this library because I heard about it, so I googled it for you, hence my short answer, but reading a bit into the results, yep it seems pretty useless... Don't think this is going to be helpful... Sorry